# Proving the adjoint nature of operators using Hermiticity

Tags: adjoint-operators

How can the fact that $\hat x$ and $\hat p$ are Hermitian be used to prove that $\hat x - \frac{i}{m \omega} \hat p$ and $\hat x + \frac{i}{m \omega} \hat p$ are adjoints of each other?

Comment: answer this simple question:
 $i^{\dagger}$=?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

For two Hemitian operators $A= A^\dagger$ and $B=B^\dagger$ and $a$  a real number you have:

$$
(A+aiB)^\dagger=A^\dagger+(aiB)^\dagger=A^\dagger-aiB^\dagger=A-aiB
$$

You can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint#Properties).